# Error reading undefined ".replace()", How can I write an if statement, if condition is undefined and concates "OOS" or .replace("undefined", "OOS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I have a discord command that scrapes the inventory of a website, but whenever a website doesn't have any stock for the item, it returns undefined. How would I replace "undefined" to "Out Of Stock". I've tried if(variant.inventory_quantity == undefined) { let updatedStock = variant.inventory_quantity.replace("undefined", "Out Of Stock")}, but when the command executes, it returns Error reading undefined ".replace()". I've also tried
"if(variant.inventory_quantity == undefined) {
let stock = variant.inventory_quantity.toString()
let updatedStock = stock .replace("undefined", "Out Of Stock")}, but I get the error "Error reading undefined ".toString()". Does anyone have any ideas?

```
        axios.get(`${newLink}.json`).then((response) => {

            if (response.data.product.variants) {
                const { product } = response.data
                let productName = product.title
                atcEmbed.setColor("#2B2F51")
                atcEmbed.setTitle(`Product Found! `)
                atcEmbed.setURL(link)
                atcEmbed.setThumbnail(product.images[0].src)
                product.variants.forEach((variant) => {
                    let cleanlink = link.split('?').toString()
                    let partarr = cleanlink.split("/")
                    cleanlink = partarr.slice(0,3).join('/')
                    var updatedLink = cleanlink + "/cart/" + variant.id + ":1".toString()
    
                    atcEmbed.setDescription(`**Product:** ${productName}\n**Price:** ${variant.price}\n**SKU:** ${variant.sku}`)
                    atcEmbed.addFields({ name: `${variant.title}`, value: `[ATC](${updatedLink})\n**Stock:** ${variant.inventory_quantity}\n${variant.id}`, inline: true })
                })
```

Comment: Please provide more code, we are not even seeing the declaration of "productName".

Comment: `undefined` is not a string, so `if(variant.inventory_quantity == undefined) { let updatedStock = variant.inventory_quantity.replace("undefined", "Out Of Stock")}` will not work since there is no string to replace within. You could possibly do `if(variant.inventory_quantity == undefined) { let updatedStock = "Out Of Stock"}`

Comment: You simply want `variant.inventory_quantity ?? "Out of stock"`.